# Jquery ui slider controls not updating value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've set up a JQuery UI range slider with controls, although when clicking on the controls the value sent to a select dropdown is not updated. How could I fix this?

```
var gmin = 0;
var gmax = 500;

var s =  $( "#slider" ).slider({
    value:5,
    min: gmin,
    max: gmax,
    step: 100,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#select span" ).html(ui.value);
    }
});
$('#down').click(function() {       
    s.slider('value', s.slider('value') + s.slider( "option", "step" ) );   
});

$('#up').click(function() {
    s.slider('value', s.slider('value') - s.slider( "option", "step" ) );   
});
```

View [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nrNX8/511/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this event wont store value for this element, besides here is workaround:

http://jsfiddle.net/nrNX8/514/

You have to add

```
$('#select span').text(s.slider('value'));
```

It may be useful for any element you want to set in any update.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the [`change`](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-change) event, not `slide` here. `slide()` only catches manual user slides, not programmatic ones:

```
var s =  $( "#slider" ).slider({
    value:5,
    min: gmin,
    max: gmax,
    step: 100,
    change: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#select span" ).html(ui.value);
    }
});
```

(Any reason your down button makes it go up and vice versa?)

Comment: Good tip but the slider doesn't update when live sliding anymore, only when I end the drag.

Comment: Maybe use both events then.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add this line to the click functions:

```
$( "#select span" ).html(s.slider('value'));
```

...on `#up` and `#down` listeners.

However, it seems that Ivan's answer is a better approach than mine

Comment: If you feel that Ivan's answer is better, why not upvote it?